# I want to fix the problem of EmptyView being displayed and then ContentView being displayed when data is available

Tags: swiftui

Obtaining the user ID on the viewModel.
The FreeView will dispatch the view depending on whether the userID was obtained or not.

I'm having a problem with ContentView being displayed after EmptyView is displayed if I can get the userID, and I'd like an idea to solve this problem.

If the userID is empty after fetching, EmptyView
If it is not empty, we want to display ContentView.

If it is not empty, EmptyView will be displayed and then ContentView will be displayed.

Here's a sample source code

```swift
struct FreeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var freeViewViewModel: FreeViewViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
            if self.freeViewViewModel.userID.isEmpty {
                // EmptyView
            } else {
                // Content View
            }
        }
    }
}

final class FreeViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userID: [String] = []
    
    init() {
        self.fetchUserID()
    }
    private func fetchUserID() {
        // get userID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `ContentView` updated make the following

```
private func fetchUserID() {
    // get userID
    
    // ... your fetch request here ...

        // ... error response handing here

       // in callback of your async fetcher do like the following
       guard let fetchedUserId = fetchedUserId else { return }

       DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.userID = [fetchedUserId]
       }
    }
}
```